# Ajustar la fecha usando Calendar. Error de AM-PM

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero crear un objeto Calendar, pero como puedo hacer para que me tome una hora y minutos dados y me ajuste la fecha?

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR,hora); //valores tomados de un TimePickerDialog
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutos); //valores tomados de un TimePickerDialog
```

Para comprobar que este bien lo escribo en el Logcat. Lo que pasa es que cuando pongo por ejemplo las: 5:30 am al usar

```
c.getTime().toString()
```

me muestra: `Fri Mar 30 17:30:00 GMT-04:00 2018` o sea me invierte de am a pm y viceversa. Que puede causar esto?? También, si son las 16:30 del sábado y le pongo las 16:15, se supone que me ponga las 16:15 pero del domingo no?? Pero me muestra las: 16:15 del sábado. Supongo que sea por lo de am y pm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa   [Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) en lugar de `Calendar.HOUR`, por ejemplo :

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hora);
```

> [Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) es usado para definir un formato de 24
>   horas.

---

de esta forma definiendo 5:30 obtendrías:

```
Fri Mar 30 05:30:00 GMT-04:00 2018
```

otro ejemplo, si defines 16:15

```
Fri Mar 30 16:15:00 GMT-04:00 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

En Calendar debes de usar HOUR_OF_DAY para configurar la hora, en formato 24 horas:

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hora);
```

Si estas usando SimpleDateFormat, para mostrar la hora, por ej las 2:30 pm:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")    //14:30
new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm")    // 2:30
new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")  // 2:30 PM
```